# ImageMagick PHP writeimage() does not create new image file

Tags: php, imagemagick, distortion

I am writing a code to distort an existing image, then save the new image in a separate file. Images are .jpg
The image is distorted and

```
echo $image;
```

displays the distorted image to the browser, but

```
$image->writeImage("newimage.jpg");
```

does not save the new image in a seperate file. No error messages.

Why?

Comment: Have you checked your logs and your permissions?

Comment: Yes, I had to change the permission to be able to write to the folder. Thanks for pointing to this.

Comment: Did that solve the problem? If so, I will post my comment as an answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell Yes it did. You can post it as an answer. Thanks